# EventBus.clearStickyEvents is not "static"?

Tags: android, droidparts

I`m use EventBus.postEventSticky to post message for close all activities，but it will close quickly when restart the app, i think the pre message is exist, so i want to clear the message, but the method EventBus.clearStickyEvents is not "static", how can i to use this method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was fixed in 1.6.0.